# How do I control REXML formatting on added elements?

Tags: xml, ruby, rexml

I am a adding a couple of simple elements to a bunch of XML files (plists). The existing XML element I am working on looks like this:

```
<dict>
  <key>background</key>
  <string>#FFFFFF</string>
  <key>caret</key>
  <string>#000000</string>
  <key>foreground</key>
  <string>#000000</string>
  <key>invisibles</key>
  <string>#BFBFBF</string>
  <key>lineHighlight</key>
  <string>#00000012</string>
  <key>selection</key>
  <string>#BAD6FD</string>
</dict>
```

I have captured this element in an object called `settings` and I am adding new `<key>` and `<string>` elements, and adding some text to those elements. Simple enough so far:

```
settings.add_element('key').add_text('gutter')
settings.add_element('string').add_text('#282828')
```

Trouble is, when I write this back out, the XML looks like this (note the last line):

```
<dict>
  <key>background</key>
  <string>#FFFFFF</string>
  <key>caret</key>
  <string>#000000</string>
  <key>foreground</key>
  <string>#000000</string>
  <key>invisibles</key>
  <string>#BFBFBF</string>
  <key>lineHighlight</key>
  <string>#00000012</string>
  <key>selection</key>
  <string>#BAD6FD</string>
<key>gutter</key><string>#282828</string></dict>
```

I am using the [`write (REXML::Document)`](http://www.germane-software.com/software/XML/rexml/doc/classes/REXML/Document.html#M000502) method to write out the XML (to $stdout at the moment):

```
tmtheme.write( $stdout )
```

Also tried

```
tmtheme.write( $stdout, 2 )
```

But these don't return the desired results. The following looked promising:

```
tmtheme.write( $stdout, 2, true )
```

But this gives me a [known error](http://trac.germane-software.com/rexml/ticket/170). Update: just tried it on Ruby 1.9 and although I don't get the erro, it doesn't help - I still get the formatting as seen in the example above.

Can anyone tell me how I can format the XML so that it conforms to the formatting style of the rest of the document? It doesn't necessarily need to be done with REXML.

Comment: Have you had a look at REXML::Formatters::Pretty? Note however that it may add some unwanted whitespace to your <string>s and <key>s.

Comment: @Inshalla, pretty printing almost works, but as you say, it adds unwanted whitespace - in this case, it adds newlines were I don't want them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robert Klemme and Aaron Patterson [came up with the goods](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/195353) on the ruby-talk list.

This is the first time a question I've posed on SoF has drawn a complete blank.